# Azure Mobile Services : GET operation from table

Tags: get, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to get data from a table I created in Azure Mobile Services.
When I setup the service, I created a new database to go along with it.

I've added a row of data to my table called TODOITEM and can query this row of data fine from the db admin tool on Azure.

Now what I'm trying to do is run a GET request on this table, as documented here...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj677199.aspx

I am using Fiddler and trying to send the following request with HTTP 1.1...

https://mobilemeshtest.azure-mobile.net/tables/todoitem

X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: my azure mobile services key

X-ZUMO-AUTH: my facebook authentication key

Host: mobilemeshtest.azure-mobile.net

No matter what I try, all I get back is a 404 not found.
I'm even copying what the guy did in a PluralSight video tutorial on Azure Mobile Services, and he gets a correct 200 response.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED : I was using a .NET backend, it seems one has to publish their data objects and controllers first using Visual Studio.

[This blog post](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-leaderboard/) has a good example on how to achieve this.

If I was using the Javascript backend option, the controllers are automatically setup for you.

Answer (score 0):

404 is pretty simple. The url is wrong. 
Propably you have not set your Controller right. 
If your Controller is named SomethingController then the route is /tables/Something assuming you havent customized the default Routing methods

Application Key and Authorization Key is not needed if you haven't specified the corresponding authorization attribute
 for example : [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]